# Issue with external jars in Android

Tags: android, opencmis

I'm getting

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.CmisBindingFactory`

for external jars when executing through emulator.

I've done following things -

1. Created libs folder under root package and keep all external jars under libs folder.
   libs folder contains : activation-1.1.jar, android-support-v4.jar, chemistry-opencmis-client-api-0.8.0.jar, chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-0.8.0.jar, chemistry-opencmis-commons-api-0.8.0.jar, chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl-0.8.0.jar
2. Then go to Project Properties -> java Build path -> Order and Export and select the checkbox against Android Dependency and Android 4.2
3. Clean project

But still not able to solve this. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Right click** on the project, select **Android Tools->Add Support Library**

Or, **Right click** the **Project**->**Properties**->**Android**.

At the bottom of that screen you should see the Android libraries you're including and whether they are correctly linked or not.

If you see any external jar missing there, **right click** on the **external jar file** in the you have in the **libs folder** and then select **Build Path -> Add to Build Path**.

Check [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/cyberycon/archive/2011/05/17/using-external-libraries-with-android.aspx) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was one jar was missing which was called by another jar.